# Are java.util.Queue poll and add methods Atomic/thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to implement a Connection Pool, which has methods getFromPool and returnToPool

```
private java.util.Queue<XXXConnection> xxxConnectionQueue;  


public XXXConnection get() {
    XXXConnection xxxConnection = null;

        if (semaphore.tryAcquire()) {
            confServerProtocol = configServerConnectionQueue.poll();
        }

    return confServerProtocol;
}


protected void returnToPool(XXXConnection xxxConnection) {
    if (xxxConnectionValidator.isValid(xxxConnection)) {
        if(xxxConnectionQueue.add(xxxConnection)) {
            semaphore.release();                
        }
    }
}
```

Here xxxConnectionValidatorChecks whether connection is a valid connection or not before connection is returned to the pool.
Wanted to confirm whether add and poll methods of java.util.Queue are thread safe or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.util.Queue` is an interface, whether the implementation of that interface is thread-safe depends on which implementation you choose.

Oracle has a small page showing the various "standard" queue implementations here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/queue.html